# Mobility i18n with includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mobility

I'm using `includes` to avoid N+1 queries. However, I'm using Mobility in nested elements. This is what I've tried, but I'm getting an error: `undefined method 'i18n' for #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation [#<FeedItem`  or `Can't join 'FeedItem' to association named 'string_translations'; perhaps you misspelled it?` if I drop `i18n` from the query.

```rb
current_user.feed_items.includes(:post).i18n.eager_load(:string_translations)
```

What is the proper way of using Mobility's eager_load on nested elements when using ActiveRecord includes?

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :feed_items, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :feed_posts, through: :feed_items, class_name: 'Post', source: :post
end
```

```rb
class FeedItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: Do these models `extend Mobility` ? You need to do that to use Mobility methods like `i18n`.

Comment: Only `Post` model which isn't shown here extends Mobility.